# How do I exclude slf4j from micronaut framework? I'm using log4j2

Tags: micronaut

How do I **exclude slf4j** from micronaut framework?

Exclude means: I DO NOT want slf4j to be a facade for log4j. I do not want any dependency on slf4j.

```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
> See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
> details. WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not
> supported. This will impact performance.
```

I included log4j2 already:

```
<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>1.2.3</version>-->
<!--      <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!--    <dependency> **I DO NOT WANT log4j-slf4j**-->
<!--      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->
```

Answer (score 1):

If you created a micronaut application via our CLI, it comes with logback. If you want to switch to log4j simply add `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.12.1`, `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.12.1`, `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.12.1` and remove `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3`

Comment: Thanks for the info,  Didn't test the above.  Not using Mnaut anymore, will have to rethink if I've to go with Quarcus, or straight to Golang like framework.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [link](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) in log message:

> Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.

For me, adding the following dependency solved the problem:

> runtimeOnly "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"